# What is origin of suffix '-stan', as in Hindustan, Afghanistan?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

As a supplementary, is -stan related to 'sthan' (Sanskrit)?

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-stan) appears to answer this. If it doesn't, please edit the question to explain the deficiency.

Comment: The answer to this can be easily found by [looking up the suffix on Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=-stan), which is one of the websites that count as General Reference here. If you’re looking specifically for Sanskrit cognates, it is related to the very common verb _tiṣṭhati_ ‘to stand’. I am not familiar with the word _sthan_ (स्थन्), but it looks quite odd as a Sanskrit word, and no online dictionary I can find has it.

Comment: I think it is, it has to be sthan's variation. 'Sthan' is an archaic term for 'place' in Hindi. Hindustan (Hindu+sthan) means place of Hindus, Pakistan (Pak, meaning sacred+sthan) means a sacred place. Then there is Afghanistan place of Afghans and so on. My answer would be yes, 'stan' is a variation of 'sthan' from Sankrit/Hindi.

Comment: In addition to etymonline that @JanusBahsJacquet mentioned, also see the Wikipedia article on the suffix [-stan](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=-stan&oldid=660404002). It is from Persian -stān, which is cognate with Sanskrit स्थान (sthāna). (That is, the suffix -stan in the place names is not from Sanskrit, but both the Persian root and the Sanskrit root have a common origin.)